# How Do I Fix The player.Name?

Tags: lua, null, roblox

I am trying to make a system where when a person steps on a part, they get 1 win, but when 2 people jump on it at the same time, it doesn't give the next person a point.

I tried a local player script thing in there and I keep getting errors on line 18. This is my script:

```
local db = true
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)   
    if db == true then

        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
            db = false  
            local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
            plr.leaderstats.Wins.Value = plr.leaderstats.Wins.Value + 1
            wait(5)
            db = true
        end
    end
end)

local winners = {}

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local playerName = player.Name

if #winners < 2 and not winners.find(playerName) then 
    winners.insert(playerName);

end
```

What should I change here. Should I even use this bottom portion? Someone help me. Line 18 is this part of the script.

```
local playerName = player.Name
```

I used local player here:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local playerName = player.Name
```

The Output Error Message Was This:

19:35:40.940  Workspace.Truss HIll.Wins Pad.From.From.Add Wins:18: attempt to index nil with 'Name'
Stack Begin
Script 'Workspace.Truss HIll.Wins Pad.From.From.Add Wins', Line 18
Stack End  -  Server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Define player.Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633125/how-do-i-define-player-name)